# Display different Images depending on the current day

Tags: images

I need to create a grid layout with images, which change daily. So i could build a pool of images in advance for a whole month and the page shows automatically the appropriate image every day. The image could be named after the date or could be connected to this information on another way.

How do i achieve this in wordpress?

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the related images in a specific directory. Let's say the directory is `grid_images` and all the images have `jpg` extension. Then when you want to show the image, you can get the current day of the month and pull the image accordingly.

```
$image = PATH_TO_GRID_IMAGES_DIRECTORY .  date( 'j' ) . '.jpg';
```

Once you have the image variable you can use this as per your need.

**Note:** The images should be named as `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, .... , `31.jpg`